# Add column to pyspark dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My data.csv file has three columns like given below. I have converted this file to python spark dataframe.

```
  A   B    C
| 1 | -3 | 4 |
| 2 | 0  | 5 |
| 6 | 6  | 6 |
```

I want to add another column D in spark dataframe with values as Yes or No based on the condition that if corresponding value in B column is greater than 0 then yes otherwise No.

```
  A   B    C   D
| 1 | -3 | 4 | No  |
| 2 | 0  | 5 | No  |
| 6 | 6  | 6 | Yes |
```

I am not able to implement this through PySpark dataframe operations.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
df.withColumn('D', f.when(f.col('B') > 0, "Yes").otherwise("No")).show()
```

Comment: you can also import col, when directly to avoid f.when. I find it less verbose in some cases